# How can create the valuable in react native functional component and it doesn't trigger a re-render when update it?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, functional-programming

in this case, it will trigger render again when I call updateNumber(), so how can create the valuable that it is for saving data only?

```
function test() {
   const [cartNum, setCartNum] = useState(0);

  function updateNumber() {
    setCartNum(number +1);
  }
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
       <TouchableOpacity onPress={updateNumber}>
          <Text>
            {Math.random()}
          </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `useRef` hook

Example below

```
// Call on top of component 
const number = useRef(0);

const updateNumber = ()=>{
    number.current++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways for it to update and not re render:

```
// by using normal variables
function test() {
   let number = 0;

  function updateNumber() {
    number++
  }
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
       <TouchableOpacity onPress={updateNumber}>
          <Text>
            {Math.random()}
          </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}

// or as carlos mentioned by using ref

function test() {
   const number = useRef(0);

  function updateNumber() {
   number.current++;
  }
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
       <TouchableOpacity onPress={updateNumber}>
          <Text>
            {Math.random()}
          </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: thanks for your help , i will try to use useRef.

but about method 1
let number = 0;
it will resume to 0 when trigger re-render

Comment: yeah correct, ref itself is the best way, if your comp re renders, if comp re renders, then first approach is waste, depends upon your use case